# Blazor InputCheckbox @onchange event not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor form on a .RAZOR page:

```
<EditForm Model="@myModel" OnValidSubmit="@doThis">

    <InputCheckbox class="someClass" id="someId" @bind-value="booleanValue" @onchange="e=>{doSomething(e);}"></InputCheckbox>

</EditForm>

@code {

    public MyModel myModel = new MyModel();

    public bool booleanValue = true;

    public void doSomething(ChangeEventArgs e) {
        // Stuff here ...
    }

    public async Task doThis(){
        // Stuff here ...
    }

}
```

When I put a breakpoint at `public void DoSomething` it never gets hit.

However, if I change the `@onchange` to `@onclick`, the `public void DoSomething` method gets hit every time. The only thing is that the `@onclick` doesn't let me know what has changed, meaning "is it clicked -to-> unclicked or is it unclicked -to-> clicked".

So, why is the `@onchange` event never firing, and how can I get it to work?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (I'm still learning Blazor), but I think `@bind-value` overrides OnChange on a checkbox. If you are using .NET 7 you can try `@bind-value:after="e=>{doSomething(e);}"`.

Comment: @mxmissile - You are correct.

Comment: How many human lives' worth of time would have been saved if Blazor had started off with the `:after` tag? :D

Answer (score 1):

`@bind-Value` overrides `OnChange` on a Blazor checkbox.  If you are using .NET 7 you can use `@bind-Value:after="e=>{doSomething(e);}"`.

If you are not on .NET 7, you can set `booleanValue` as a property and use your `set` block; to figure out if it was changed and call `doSomething(e)` accordingly:

```
private bool _booleanValue;
protected bool booleanValue {
  get{ return _booleanValue; }
  set
  {
    if(value != _booleanValue) doSomething(e);
    _booleanValue = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: @bind-Value. V is capital.

Answer (score 0):

The best way and simplest to achieve this is by doing this:

```
<input class="someClass" id="someId" type="checkbox" checked="@booleanValue" 
    @onchange="(e) => doSomething(e)"/>
```

Using InputCheckBox if you need to use @onchange, you can follow this example I have for a nullable bool in an authomatic generated form which is as complex as InputCheckBox can get:

```
@foreach (var obj in associate.ExtraInfoValues)
{
    ....
    else if (key.Type == Enums.ExtraInfo.Type.Bool)
    {
        bool tmp = false;
        <div class="col-1 extraInfo">
            <label>@key.Key:</label>                            
            <InputCheckbox id="@key.Key" class="form-control" TValue="bool?" ValueExpression="() => tmp" Value="Convert.ToBoolean(obj.Value)" ValueChanged="((arg) => obj.Value = arg.ToString())" />
         </div>                            
     } 
 }
```

For your case if it is just a simple bool value you can use like this:

```
<InputCheckbox id="someId" class="someClass" TValue="bool" ValueExpression="() => booleanValue" Value="booleanValue" ValueChanged="((e) => doSomething(e))" />
```

Comment: I tried all your examples here, but it didn't work. I keep getting the error: `InputCheckbox requires a value for the 'ValueExpression' parameter. Normally this is provided automatically when using 'bind-value'`

Comment: @Brian look that the first example I give is not using "InputCheckBox", instead uses "input" which will not throw that error. Also both bellow examples have the "ValueExpression" defined so they should not throw that error..